# passport session not created when using request

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, request, passport.js

I'm using passportJS to handle login and persistent sessions on a server backend.

Sessions work correctly when passing requests from the server frontend (a webpage that I did not create, and don't have enough knowhow to mess with) , but when using request (https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) to manually send requests to the server, sessions don't work at all -- deserializeUser is not called, req.user is undefined.

This is the relevant piece of code from the frontend.

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: GE.SERVER_URL + '/publish',
    data: {
      name: $( '#new_publication_name' ).val(),
      code: column.editor.getValue(),
      language: column.mode,
      permissions: $( '#new_publication_permissions' ).prop( 'checked' ),
      tags: $( '#new_publication_tags' ).val().split(','),
      notes: $( '#new_publication_notes' ).val(), 
      instrument: false,
      username: Gibber.Environment.Account.nick
     },
    dataType:'json'
  })
  .done( function ( data ) {        
    if( data.error ) {
      GE.Message.post( 'There was an error writing to Gibber\'s database. Error: ' + data.error )
    }else{
      GE.Message.post( 'Your publication has been saved to: ' + GE.SERVER_URL + '/?path=' + data._id )
    }
```

This is the code I'm using.

```
request.post({url:'http://127.0.0.1:8080/publish',form:{filename:"steinfile", code:"john doe", language:"english",tags:["testfile"],notes:"thesearenotes"}}, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body);
    }
    else
    {
        console.log(error);
    }
})
```

Thanks!

Comment: With your request.post you don't send cookies which is needed for session to work correctly. I guess that is the problem.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it. I'm not sure how to mark your comment as the correct solution though.

Comment: Adde answer so you can mark it as correct. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't send cookies along with your `request.post`.

They are needed for session to work correctly.